# SQL: Filtering out customers who have not purchased over the past year

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a couple tables with information on customers, their account information, and transactions/sales. Numerous customers can be on an account, but I want to find the number of accounts who have not purchased anything over the past year.

```
Customer table = 
individual id
date added
first transaction date
gnc account number

Account table = 
account number
date added
expiration date
first transaction date
last purchase date

Transactions table = 
transaction id
sales date 
account number (null when customer doesn't have an account)
```

What things do I need incorporate into a query (subquery, etc) where I exclude those accounts where they did not perform a transaction over the past one year.

Comment: This is pretty basic and screams of homework. What have you tried?

Comment: http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/  Pay particular attention to what a LEFT outer join does.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the last purchase date is correct, you just need a simple query like:

```
select a.*
from accounts a
where LastPurchaseDate >= dateadd(year, -1, getdate());
```

If you want the number, use `select count(*)` rather than `select a.*`.

If you want the number who have not made a purchase, then use `<` rather than `>=`.

Comment: This also assumes that purchases are the only type of transaction.

Comment: @TabAlleman . . . The question is:  " I want to find the number of accounts who have not purchased anything over the past year".

Comment: Well, it also says:  "What things do I need incorporate into a query (subquery, etc) where I exclude those accounts where they did not perform a transaction over the past one year."   soooo... : )

Answer (score 0):

PSEUDO CODE:

```
SELECT some columns 
FROM the account table
LEFT OUTER JOIN to INCLUDE ALL the accounts and only those that match from transaction
  on the account number 
 and the salesdate >= sysdate-365 (assuming this is a year)
```

Avoid using a where clause unless the limit is on the account table.. if you filter on the transaction table in the where clause it changes the outer join to an inner join as it will exclude the nulls (unless you OR each where clause criteria)